# Override React AgGrid styling settings using createStyles and withStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I'm aware that it's possible to override Ag Grid properties by editing the CSS itself, however I'm wondering if it's possible to use the functionalities built into react to do this instead. I'm relatively new to the two frameworks, so apologies if there's something I'm not understanding.

Ultimately, what I want to do is something like this:

```
styles.js
---------
const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      position: 'relative',
      height: 'calc(100vh - 128px)',
    },

    agHeaderCellLabel: {
      agHeaderCellText: {
        writingMode: 'vertical-lr',
        marginTop: '100px',
      },
    },
  })

export default styles
```

```
GridComponent.tsx
-----------------

import styles from './styles'
...

return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
     <div
          id="myGrid"
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
          }}
          className={`ag-theme-material ${classes.agHeaderCellLabel}`}
        >
          <AgGridReact
            // listening for events
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
            onRowSelected={onRowSelected}
            onCellClicked={onCellClicked}
            onModelUpdated={calculateRowCount}
            // Data
            columnDefs={cDef}
            defaultColDef={defaultColumnFormat}
            suppressRowClickSelection={true}
            groupSelectsChildren={true}
            debug={true}
            rowSelection="multiple"
            // rowGroupPanelShow={this.state.rowGroupPanelShow}
            enableRangeSelection={true}
            pagination={true}
            rowData={rows}
         />
        </div>
    </Paper>
)
...

export withStyles(styles)(GridComponent)
```

In this example I'm just trying to get the header text to be displayed vertically.

I've inherited this project, and I've noticed that all of the styling has been done in this method, as there are no custom css files lying around, so I'm trying to stick with that convention of a styles file alongside the component.

Is this possible, and if so,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same situation, and came up with the following solution. Although not necessarily *ideal*, it allows you to continue with the desired convention.

```
styles.js
---------
const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      position: 'relative',
      height: 'calc(100vh - 128px)',
    },

    //Apply changes to agGrid material HeaderRoot
    myClassAppliedToGrid: {
      '& .ag-header[ref="headerRoot"]':{
        writingMode: 'vertical-lr',
        marginTop: '100px',
      }
    }

   //OR        

   //Apply Changes to agGrid material header row
    myClassAppliedToGrid: {
      '& .ag-header-row':{
        writingMode: 'vertical-lr',
        marginTop: '100px',
      }
    }
  })

export default styles
```

The key idea is using the & SASS syntax to "reach into" agGrid and make more specific CSS classes so you can override them. (see https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/ for more info)

The key pieces of info are:

```
.parent {
  & .child {}
}
```

turns into

```
.parent .child {}
```

and

```
.some-class {
  &.another-class {}
}
```

turns into

```
.some-class.another-class { }
```

Using this sytanx, you should be able to create CSS classes that you can apply to your grid, columns, rows, etc that will properly override the material ag-grid theme.

Here is another example, but this class gets applied to a cell using agGrid cellStyleRules when a row is dragged over it, rather than applying the class to the grid as a whole. This way it only effects cells that have a row drag occuring over them:

```
    rowDraggedOverCellsTopEdge: {
        '&.ag-cell': {
            borderTopColor: theme.palette.gray[50],
            borderTopWidth: 8,
            backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.gray[50], 0.3)
        }
   },
```

Finally, one thing I did not do but would reccommend investigating is looking into agGrid's theme overriding, especially if you are on version 23+

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-provided/#customising-themes

It might be a good idea to get your base overrides to the theme done this way if you expect a consistent look and feel of your grids throughout the application.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! 

For the time being I had just created a .css file directly adjacent to my component file and imported it last so that it would override the theme import for AgGrid, but this does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Ok, In general this works, however for my specific case it's still a little wonky. How much does the top level name matter? (in your example you named it agHeaderCell). Does it have to match what you'd actually find in the css file, except in camel case instead? and second, what is the `[ref="headerRoot"]` doing?

Comment: The top level name doesn't matter; and I updated the answer to reflect this. Most generally, you can apply that CSS class to the grid as a whole, and then use selectors to reach down. You just need to be sure that your CSS class is more specific than the one in agGrid. In your case, using "& .ag-header-row" should sufficient. The [ref="headerRoot"] was to increase specificity as agGrids "Header Root" has ref="headerRoot" on the element, so that selector allows me to target that. In the case of updating header look and feel, you may want to look into custom header renderers as well

Comment: Note, beyond convention this is especially helpful when composing grid components. This is because you can easily modify the style of the grid once you create classes that target key styling elements of the grid. You can do this by passing values to the classes prop of the underlying grid component.